# Return value in python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

```
import urllib,re

def getver():
    url='https://github.com/Bendr0id/xmrigCC/releases'
    website = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = website.read()
    links = re.findall(r'(?<=<a href=")[^"]*\bgcc-win64.zip\b', html)
    link=links[0]
    version=link.split('/')
    ver0=version[5]
    return ver0
getver()
```

I've tried to run the code but it doesnt output anything,instead when I replace return with print it prints out the correct answer which is 1.5.2 . 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code that doesn't print anything doesn't print anything. That's expected behavior. You're not doing anything wrong. If you want to print something, you have to call `print` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
print(getver())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been fooled by the interactive interpeter's friendly habit of printing out the results of any bare expressions you enter.

This does not happen when you run a program, so you need to ensure you output values specifically by using the print statement.

This is specifically mentioned in [a rather obscure portion of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements) dealing with the language's grammar.